# No route matches [DELETE] "/signout"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out why my Signout link isn't working to properly destroy the user session.

If I manually navigate to `localhost:3000/signout`, it works fine - destroying the session. But if I click my signout link, I get a `No route matches [DELETE] "/signout"` error.

Here's how I create my link:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
```

The html:

```
<a data-method="delete" href="/signout" rel="nofollow">Sign out</a>
```

My routes file:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users 

  match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'get'
```

I'm guessing it has to do with how I'm creating my link. I've tried a few other variations but they all seem to throw the same error. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your signout path accessible via `delete` HTTP method instead of `get`:

```
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `method: "delete"` from the link:-

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path %>
```

Comment: This works, but I'm guessing that Marek's answer is probably a better route since it shouldn't be via get?